# Was running QA on a piece I wrote, and I have no idea why the last if statement won't return anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

Running on python  3.8

I was creating a menu when I realized that I needed a way to "loop" the menu if the user tried to make an invalid selection, but the final if statement basically doesn't evaluate at all.

```
def menu():
    print("1) Generator Parameters\n2) AI Parameters\n3) Help")

    choice = input("\nX ")

    # converting choice to an int here
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        clear()
        print("You are in the Generator sub-menu")

    if choice == 2:
        clear()
        print("You are  in the AI sub-menu")

    if choice == 3:
        clear()
        print("You are in the help sub-menu")

    if 0 >= choice > 3:
        clear()
        print("Please make a valid selection\n")
        input()


menu()
```

I've looked through other solutions for similar issue, however most of them being in different languages I wasn't able to identify a possible problem. (I'm new to programming)

I've run inputs 1, 2 and 3 all successfully, but anything other than those evaluates to just a blank line and a code 0.

Any ideas why I'm not getting anything?

(clear() is a function that uses system.os to write "cls" to the command line, just clearing the CLI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend making two additional changes.

> 1. Change you input line. The input line allows you to enter a prompt so you dont need a separate print statement. You can also convert the
>      choice to int right in the int statement. It can be awkward to modify
>      a variable and reassign it to the same name as you had previously
>      done.
> 2. Use proper if format of if, elif, else. As your code currently stands if a 1 is entered your code will check if choice == 1 which is
>      true, but then will also check if choice == 2 then choice == 3 then
>      choice < 1 or choice > 3. With the setup below if will break out of
>      the if else once a match is made and the else statement will better
>      handle unexpected results.
>
> Finally, it isn't clear what clear() does here. Is it a custom method?

```
choice = int(input("1) Generator Parameters\n2) AI Parameters\n3) Help\n"))

if choice == 1:
    clear()
    print("You are in the Generator sub-menu")

elif choice == 2:
    clear()
    print("You are  in the AI sub-menu")

elif choice == 3:
    clear()
    print("You are in the help sub-menu")

else:
    clear()
    print("Please make a valid selection\n")
    input()
```

Comment: Hadn't considered doing it this way before. And the clear() is calling a function that uses os.system to write "cls" to the command line for windows operators. Just clears the CLI basically. I'll clarify that

Answer (score 1):

You want to do:

```
if choice <= 0 or choice > 3:
```

Because right now you are doing `is choice lesser than or equal to zero and at the same time greater than three`